# Laravel 9 PHP - check if email already exists

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-9

I'm try to check if the email exists or not in my database mysql. if it exists then there will be a error message and if it does not exist then i execute the following below; else statement.

I'm having problems; `Input::get('email')->exists())`

```
error message: Undefined type 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input'.
```

My code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {   
        if (Contact::where('email', '=', **Input**::get('email'))->exists()) {


            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" style="text-align: center;" role="alert">De email bestaat al. <p>Probeer een andere email.</p></div>';
            return view('contact.create');

        } else {
            $input = $request->all();
            Contact::create($input);
            return redirect('contact')->with('flash_message', 'contact toegevoegt');
        }

    }
```

I have try'd:

- watching yt video's
- google search
- stackoverflow answered questions

Comment: The Input::get() doesn't seem to work?

Comment: What is `**Input**` ? You should try `$request->input('email')`.

Comment: @Cositanto yes that helped kinda.

Comment: @Cositanto i have tested and it didn't work.

Comment: @Cositanto now i need check if the email already is taken in db

Comment: You should use [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique) instead...